# C# get every cursor position

Tags: c#, cursor

How can i get every cursor movement thats done by the user? even if its out of my form?
on google i see getcursorpos but how to get that function? or is there something else?

THNX!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a hook using the windows API. For general information on hooks using windows api see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960(VS.85).aspx) and codeproject seems to have an explanation on global hooks  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) and some other random code example giving enable and disable hooks [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/6ac8e418-f91a-40a2-9ac4-084288144ef3/). I have tested non of those last two though. So I suggest you dive a bit into the windows api hook information (first link) and write one yourself :).